# How to start several docker images created with compose and uploaded to another server?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I created the `docker-compose.yml` file with some services: db - wordpress - phpmyadmin.

I exported the services with the command:

```
docker save $(docker images | sed '1d' | awk '{print $1 ":" $2 }') -o allinone.tar
```

I imported them on the new server with the command:

```
docker load -i allinone.tar
```

Now the result of `docker images` is the following:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED         SIZE
mysql               8.0                 86xxxxxd20        x days ago        xxxxB
wordpress           latest              bxxxxxxe65        x days ago        xxxxB
phpmyadmin          latest              cfxxxxae14        x days ago        xxxxB
```

I don't understand how I can start them exactly as I had them on the other server.

If I use docker-compose, it says I don't have the yml file, do I have to recreate it every time?

Maybe I should have created a build with docker build?

**EDIT:**
i am using this configuration for testing purpose:

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
    volumes: 
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    networks:
      - app-network

  wordpress:
    depends_on: 
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.4.2-fpm-alpine
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=user
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - app-network

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on: 
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3333:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORT: password
    networks:
      - app-network


volumes:
  wordpress:
  dbdata:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `docker-compose.yml` file contains the orchestration between these containers.

If you want to keep this orchestration you must reuse this `yml` file and run it with `docker-compose up`.

Comment: will wordpress and db files and configurations be loaded from the backup, or will the new yml overwrite everything?
Also, what is the difference between using docker builds?

Comment: If your configurations are present in your docker images and you don't mount a volume on their locations they won't be touched. Docker builds create independant containers but you need to link them (for instance you wordpress container need to connect to your db container). For that, you can use `docker-compose`.

Comment: I tried to upload the images to the new server with docker load and started the .yml file, I still tried to run the .yml file and then load the images, my configurations are not there, the databases are empty. A clearer explanation? I'm having trouble finding a guide with the full process.

Comment: Can you add your `docker-compose.yml` file to the question ?

Comment: You mounted volumes `- dbdata:/var/lib/mysql` and `- wordpress:/var/www/html`. That means data on these paths were not saved with their containers. They are on the directories `dbdata` and `wordpress` where you deployed your `docker-compose` originally.

Comment: So the problem is a wrong file configuration. Can you write the configuration so that I can try again and understand what I'm wrong?

Comment: No, the `docker-compose` configuration is correct. You are not supposed to package data inside a docker image. You should handle them separately. To retrieve them in your new server, you must transfer them the way you transfer the `allinone.tar` and put them in the same directories in your new server. Then, apply the `docker-compose` script on that.

Comment: So there is no docker command to transfer configurations and data from one server to another? Strange that we must proceed manually, I do not find the sense. Well thank you.